# How to handle form elements with get method in django when form in not submitted

Tags: python, django, django-forms, django-views

I am new to Django-python and trying to build a single page python-django website which submits form values to itself. But how to handle .get method when form is not submitted initially?

Form:

```
<form id="filters" action="{% url 'myapp:index' %}" method="GET">
{% csrf_token %}
<label><input type="checkbox" name="abc" value="abc" checked>Include abc</label>
<label><input type="checkbox" name="pqr" value="pqr" checked>Include abc</label>
<label><input type="checkbox" name="xyz" value="xyz" checked>Include abc</label>
<input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

Views.py:

```
from django.shortcuts import render

def index(request):
    try:
        abc = request.GET['abc']
        context = {'abc':abc}
    except (KeyError):
        raise
    else:
        return render(request, 'myapp/index.html', context)
```

Now when I open index page initially for myapp, it raises

> **MultiValueDictKeyError**

which I assume is because the checkboxes are not set initially.

If I change abc = request.GET['abc'] to

```
abc = request.GET.get['abc']
```

It raises:

> **TypeError**
>   'instancemethod' object has no attribute '**getitem**'

Traceback:

> ```
>                 response = middleware_method(request, callback, callback_args, callback_kwargs)
>                 if response:
>                     break
>         if response is None:
>             wrapped_callback = self.make_view_atomic(callback)
>             try:
>                             response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs) ...
>             except Exception as e:
>                 # If the view raised an exception, run it through exception
>                 # middleware, and if the exception middleware returns a
>                 # response, use that. Otherwise, reraise the exception.
>                 for middleware_method in self._exception_middleware:
>                     response = middleware_method(request, e)
> ```

Stuck and not able to understand these errors.

Can I do something like if(!isset($_POST['submit'])) like in PHP, so that my python script is not submitted until submit is pressed?

Comment: You should be using a Django form here, as it will take care of these things for you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change it

```
abc = request.GET.get['abc']
```

to:

```
abc = request.GET.get('abc')
```

And, for check if is a GET method:
Use:

```
if request.method == 'GET':
```

Documentation of [Request Method](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/request-response/#django.http.HttpRequest.method)